# Syntax error while creating CONSTRAINT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The first table was created with no problems:

```
mysql > CREATE TABLE nodes(
     -> id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
     -> user text,
     -> uid varchar(10),
     -> version tinyint,
     -> changeset smallint,
     -> timestamp timestamp
     -> );
```

It is when I tried to create the second table that MySQL is outputting an error:

```
mysql > CREATE TABLE node_tags(
     -> id varchar(10),
     -> key text,
     -> value text,
     -> type text,
     -> CONSTRAINT pk_node_tag PRIMARY KEY (id, key),
     -> CONSTRAINT fk_node_tags_id FOREIGN KEY (id)
     ->  REFERENCES nodes (id)
     -> );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>   value text,
>   type text,
>   CONSTRAINT pk_node_tag PRIMARY KEY (id, key),
>   CONSTRAINT' at line 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This succeeds. `Key` is a reserved word, so it needs back-ticks.

Also, a text in an index limits it size as to how much of it can be indexed. It is influenced by your character set in force.

So the following runs thru:

```
drop table if exists nodes;
CREATE TABLE nodes
(   id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    user text,
    uid varchar(10),
    version tinyint,
    changeset smallint,
    timestamp timestamp
)engine=innodb;

drop table if exists node_tags;
CREATE TABLE node_tags
(   id varchar(10) not null,
    `key` text,
    value text,
    type text,
    CONSTRAINT pk_node_tag PRIMARY KEY (id, `key`(255)),
    CONSTRAINT fk_node_tags_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES nodes (id)
)engine=innodb;
```

I would highly suggest not having a `TEXT` in a primary key anyway.

Comment: Great, this went through. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. I am sorry I can't recommend something about the `key` as I know little about it. You know best with your data. Remember it is going to be way-wide so if you use it as a foreign key you may run into performance problems (certainly compared to a thin INT)

Answer (score 0):

Reserved keywords such as 'key, value, timestamp etc' shouldn't be preferred while creating columns. This induces bugs and isn't scalable.
As far as this is concerned, using backticks `key` will solve the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

because key is the reserved word in MySQL. please refer to this document to see list of the reserved words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html